# Noise generator circuit: how exactly does it work?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, noise

I came across this circuit that is supposed to generate an output noise signal, but I don't understand how it works.

I think my mistake is analyzing the circuit as if the op-amp was ideal, which I don't think is the case (it's supposed to be an LTC1152 supplied by +/- 5V.)

How should I analyze this circuit to have an idea about what the is noise?

[image]

Comment: It appears to be an extremely high gain amplifier amplifying nothing. In reality there will be some EMI, which will be amplified. The characteristics of the output would depend on the the op amp and the electrical environment surrounding it.

Comment: Note to calculate noise ... https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/document/apn/r13an0010-noise-calculations-op-amp-circuits?language=en#:~:text=Op%2Damp%20noise%20is%20a,versus%20frequency%20(Figure%203).

Comment: And here a noise calculator http://dicks-website.eu/noisecalculator/index.html

Comment: What is the input voltage noise of that opamp, and how does it compare with the Johnson noise of R13?

Answer (score 3):

With an ideal op amp the output would be primarily the amplified noise from the 1k resistor.  A 1k resistor has about \$4nV/\sqrt{Hz}\$ of thermal noise (at room temperature), so amplified by 4700 (=4.7M/1k) gives \$18.8\mu V/\sqrt{Hz}\$, which in a 20kHz bandwidth would be 2.7mV (rms) of noise.

With a real op amp, there would be extra noise from the op amp, it would be wise to reduce the DC gain to avoid DC offset issues, and the high frequencies will roll off due to the finite gain bandwidth product of the op amp.

With the LTC1152, this has a gain bandwidth product of 700kHz, so the -3dB frequency will be around 150Hz, and so the 1k will contribute around \$230\mu V\$ of noise.  However, the LTC1152 is a chopper amp, and the noise from the it is significant at some frequencies, and will swamp the \$4nV/\sqrt{Hz}\$ noise from the 1k, see:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With an ideal opamp, the output would be 0.

With this opamp -- which has an offset V of < 10 uV -- the output will be 4700 times the offset voltage -- or less than 50 mV DC. There is also internal opamp noise of about 1 uVrms -- this is also amplified to about 5 mVrms at the output.

It is impossible to predict the 'quality' of this noise -- its spectrum, and what other tones might be present.

There are better ways of obtaining noise.

Comment: Lousy old 741 and LM324/LM358 are very noisy opamps. My pink noise generator uses an obsolete Cmos digital random noise chip and some filters.